# Use jars bundled in application rather than default - Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: jar, glassfish-3

The company I work for currently has a java application supplied by another company that is designed to run on Websphere.  While it runs well on Websphere, we are in desperate need to use a 64 bit JVM given the complexity of our product and how it pertains to the necessary use of the system.  We are trying to avoid buying a license for Websphere, as it will cost a good sum of money.

I have tried to install this application on practically every Java Application Server I can find and Glassfish seems to be the most promising.  The issue it seems to have is how it processed the libraries it wants to use.

Bundled with the application is a jaxb.jar file, and a pretty old version of it.  I did a quick test with that file on a standalone application to see the version number, which came out to be 1.0.  I did use some arbitrary class inside it.  I then created a simple jsp to test the version of that same class when the application is deployed.  It came out to 2.2.6.  I know that Glassfish has a jaxb jar file of a newer version, so it is clearly using this one.

How can I force my application to use the classes in its own lib folder over the ones being used by the app server?  I feel that this is the only thing holding back Glassfish from being my replacement app server.

Note:  I did try to remove the files causing the problem from Glassfish, but then it failed to restart.  They must be necessary for the server to run.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact problem when deploying/running the webapp in GlassFish?
Can you update the jaxb jar in the application instead of tampering with the jar in GlassFish?

Maybe you can read up on GlassFish classloading hierarchy [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beadf.html). 
This might give you clues how to solve this. Especially the endorsed mechanism may be useful.